# Convert country code to country name from shell script

Tags: shell

I have a parameter passed to my shell script which is [an ISO 3166-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements), which specifies a file to process, e.g. `$1` = `'be'`.

I want to find a corresponding file, e.g. `be.pdf`, and rename it to the country name, e.g. `belgium.pdf`.

I don't even know where to start with this?

The lookup could be a CSV file, or a sql database, or something else.
I have no preferences. I just need to be able to take the input and lookup the new value and do the rename.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the mapping in a file, you can use `bash` associative arrays

```
code=$1
   # Associative array, keyed of country code
declare -A cc
while read xcc xname ; do
  cc[$xcc]=$xname
done < cc_codes.txt

  # Translate, and rename
fullname=${cc[$code]}
mv "$cc.pdf" "$fullname.pdf"
```

Map file (cc_codes.txt) is simple space separated

```
us united_states
be belgium
uk United_Kindom
...
```

Please note that this uses bash specific features

Comment: That looks great - exactly what I was looking for. Let me test it out